# Subset a dictionary of dataframes through iteration

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, iteration

I am creating a program to ingest a series of text files from 2001Q1 through 2016Q1 based upon name qualifiers which indicate the schedule/report type.  The qualifiers are referred to as keys (for lack of a better name)

```
keys=[' RI ','RCD','RCF','RCG','RCH','RCL','RCO','RCRII']
```

given a path C:\files, I create a dictionary of all eligible text files

```
files=[]
for k in keys:
    for i in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,i)) and k in i:
            files.append(i)
```

Then I create a dictionary

```
    df_dict={file[:-4].replace(" ","_"):pd.read_table(path+file,header=[0,1],index_col=0,error_bad_lines=False,dtype={'IDRSSD':object}, low_memory=False) for file in files}
```

The sample dictionary looks like:
{(Schedule_RI_2001Q1:Col1 Col2 ColN),
 (Schedule_RCO_2001Q1:Col1 Col2 ColN),
 (Schedule_RI_2005Q2: Col1 Col2 ColN)
}

in a key-value arrangement.

I need to create dictionaries from the main dictionary based on report type.  I came up with this script (I know its amateur):

```
for key in keys:
    for k in df_dict.keys():
        for v in df_dict.values():
            if key in k:
                key.strip={k:v}
```

Regardless of using key.strip or key.strip() I receive an error message, "'str' object attribute 'strip' is read-only" or "can't assign to function call", respectively.  Is there a better way to accomplish this tasks.  The reason I created the aggregate dictionary is to do some data formatting and etc.  Assistance in breaking out the dictionary would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with `key.strip = { k : v }`. Key is just a single value out of `keys`, why do you want to want to initialize it again?

Comment: I was attempting to create a dictionary using the key element from the keys list.  The ' RI ' element in the keys list has spaces, so I was using strip to remove the leading and trailing spaces.  I was hoping for RI to be a dictionary containing all schedules/reports with RI in their name.

Comment: That's exactly what I guessed. My answer should work perfectly for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly create a dictionary on `key.strip` nor `key.strip()`, because well they are functions. You can however create a temporary dictionary, and use the value returned by those functions as a key in the temporary dictionary.

This is a relatively safer method:

```
keys = ['a', 'b']
df_dict = { 'a_2010': 1, 'a_2007': 2, 'Schedule_b_2009Q1': 3 }

for key in keys:
    sub_dict[key.strip()] = {}
    for k, v in df_dict.items():
        if key in k:
            sub_dict[key.strip()][k] = v
```

Output:

```
>>> sub_dict
{'a': {'a_2007': 2, 'a_2010': 1},
 'b': {'Schedule_b_2009Q1': 3}}
```

If the above seems unecessarily complex, you can simply use `locals()` to solve this particular problem (but it's usually not a good practice to use it everywhere):

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df_dict = { 'a_2010': 1, 'a_2007': 2, 'Schedule_b_2009Q1': 3 }

for key in keys:
    locals()[key.strip()] = {}
    for k, v in df_dict.items():
        if key in k:
            locals()[key.strip()][k] = v
```

Output:

```
>>> a
{'a_2007': 2, 'a_2010': 1}
>>> b
{'Schedule_b_2009Q1': 3}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry for not being that clear.  I essentially want to create separate dictionaries only containing DataFrames that correspond to a certain element in the "keys" list.  For example, RCRII_dict would contain all the "Schedule_RCRII" DataFrames in the df_dict dictionary.

Comment: @RobertGarrison, if that's the case, my answer will work perfectly for you. The first solution will return a dictionary as follows `{ 'RI': { 'RI_2010': value, 'Schedule_RI_2016Q1': value2 }, 'RCD' ... }` so on and so forth. 2nd solution will create dictionary with name as `key`.

Comment: @RobertGarrison Edited the answer to include example output.